# Having trouble making the media queries work properly.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to the world of responsiveness (keep that in mind).
I have the following media queries which are listed below and some of them work and some of them don't. 
The ones that work are: 
    `@media only screen 
    and (min-width : 320px) 
    and (max-width : 480px)` and `@media only screen 
    and (min-width : 320px) 
    and (max-width : 480px)`

But the other ones don't work. 
The way I check out whether they work is through uploading the files/folders online through FileZillah and then I check it out on http://www.responsinator.com/

My question is why do the other media queries not work expect for these two?
And if you know a better website than the responsinator, please do share :)

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */}

/*iPhone 5 in portrait & landscape*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/* Styles */}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */} 

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */}
```

Comment: About another tool: Firefox has a feature, to test different screen-sizes. http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/new-firefox-developer-tools-will-help-you-build-responsive-websites/

Comment: Thx for sharing Maja!
This is actually very helpful. 

Do you also have any idea why some media queries are working for me and others are not?

Comment: I see, that you're using 2 different syntaxes: `min-width` and `min-device-width`. I guess that the second syntax, with the additional `device`-keyword, is being interpreted wrong by the site you're using (and probalby also by firefox) http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Comment: You might need to test it on the devices itself, our you only use `min-width`, and forget about the `min-device-width`

Comment: Hey Maja, 

You actually gave me a correct answer! It was indeed not working correctly because I was using 2 different syntaxes. 
I had been through it before and had changed the syntaxes and it didn't work before. Your comment convinced me to try it again and I realise I must have gone over it without applying the correct changes before. 

Anyway, I am very thankful. 
And if you like you can post your comment as an answer so that I may give you the full points for it :)

Thanks!

Comment: I posted it as an aswer, glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 different syntaxes in your css-Code: `min-width`, and `min-device-width`.

The reason is, that there can be a difference between a "device-Pixel" and a "CSS-Pixel" - especially on Apple's Retina-Displays. Devices with such high resultions often map 1 css-pixel to several device-pixels.

`width`: refers to the number of css-Pixels

`device-width` refers to the width of the device itself, in other words, the screen resolution of the device

*(More information can be found here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml)*

I guess that the second syntax, with the additional `device`-keyword, is being interpreted wrong by the site you're using - it only changes the width, but the device-width always stays the same.

I would suggest reducing the number of media-queries. In most cases, so much different syntaxes are not neccessary, and they also decrease the readability and maintainability of your Code.

**About the Question with another tool:**

I suggest using the Browser itself, to test the responsibilty of your site. It's much more convenient than uploading your code to an online-platform after each change.

Firefox offers a built-in feature for testing different screen-resolutions, which can be very useful:
http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/new-firefox-developer-tools-will-help-you-build-responsive-websites/

And there are also many extensions for Chrome.